# What happens when a stringstream is flushed in c++?

Tags: c++, io, stream

I recently learned that `std::stringstream` objects can be flushed. What does flushing do? Is it specified by the standard, or is it implementation dependent, and does `flush` have to do anything when called?

Comment: I assume it just inherits `flush`, but I very much doubt it does anything because flushing it doesn't make sense. But I could be wrong, so I'm not answering.

Comment: Look at your compiler's STL implementation source code to see exactly what flushing does, or does not do.

Answer (score 0):

Any stream which inherits from an `std::ostream<Type>` is 'backed' by a buffer of type `std::streambuf<Type>`. When you output to an `ostream`, you are really outputting into an intermediate `std::streambuf`. When the `streambuf` is filled with data it will call its own method `std::streambuf::sync()` and this flushes the data into the stream.

If the stream were some character type of device (a console, a serial port, etc.) then `sync()` would empty some or all of the data into the receiving device.

In this case, the receiving device is yet another buffer. It would make sense from an implementation perspective that this buffer (`char` type in the case of `std::strstream`) that there would not be intermediate buffering since the receiving buffer has no extra latency w/respect to the `streambuf`.

But - this is implementation dependent. In order to insure that the receiving buffer is not actually waiting for the streambuf to fill, it would be prudent to call `flush()` before expecting the receiving buffer to be complete before using it.

Realize the call to `flush()` this is user context dependent. You should also expect `flush()` to incur performance penalties when used in the case of a non-buffer end point (like a console, serial port, USB end point, etc.).